# How to write a deep where clause in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, where-clause

I'm trying to write a where clause in PowerShell that checks if the `$root` contains a basetemplate with an ID equal to the `$template`.
I can access the basetemplates on items using `$item.Template.BaseTemplates[x].ID`.

In C# I would be able to write something like this

```
items.Where(item => item.BaseTemplates.Any(template => template.ID == "id");
```

So how would I translate this into PowerShell?

```
$root = Get-Item .
$template = "{E54BB0A6-C296-4D35-BE6A-93E71E2B9F52}"
#Write-Host $root.Template.BaseTemplates[0].ID
$items = Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path $root.FullPath -Language *

#how to do the same query on these $items?
$filteredItems = items | Where-Object { $_.Template.BaseTemplates???.ID -eq $template}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-in` to filter all templates that basetemplates contains your `$template`:

```
$filteredItems = items | Where-Object { $template -in $_.Template.BaseTemplates.ID}
```

Comment: I didn't know an array would actually list all the values for a property of its children when asking the array. That's interesting. This works great, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to see people that wan't to adopt theire C# skills to PowerShell ;-)